# podrian decirme como hacerlo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo que hacer esta tarea y no se mucho de sql, apenas lo conozco y desearia que me orienten

- Crear una base de datos llamada Cedulacion, que contendrá una tabla llamada Ciudadanos, con todos los datos de la cédula de identidad dominicana.
- Insertar 5 registros.

Comment: No está complicado, hay bastantes tutoriales. El sitio no está pensado en hacer tareas pero si tienes dudas con el código que hagas, eso si es bien recibido.

Comment: sii broo es lo que necesito

Comment: @EstivenRosarioEstevez las preguntas que solo exponen enunciados de tareas sin mayor evidencia de trabajo o investigación por parte de quien expone la duda no son bien vistas y terminan cerradas, te recomiendo: 1. leer [ask], 2. hacer el [tour] y 3. exponer idealmente estas dudas a tu docente debería ser ese el primer paso y posterior ya con un avance y dudas claras si podemos ayudar

Comment: Siempre date un momento para navegarle en internet y seguro encuentras material de ayuda: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/sqlserverya/